# LEFT OUTER JOIN and only return the first match

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, outer-join

Imagine the following two tables, named "Users" and "Orders" respectively:

```
ID  NAME
1   Foo
2   Bar
3   Qux


ID  USER  ITEM  SPEC  TIMESTAMP
1   1     12    4     20150204102314
2   1     13    6     20151102160455
3   3     25    9     20160204213702
```

What I want to get as the output is:

```
USER   ITEM  SPEC  TIMESTAMP
1      12    4     20150204102314
2      NULL  NULL  NULL
3      25    9     20160204213702
```

In other words: do a LEFT OUTER JOIN betweeen Users and Orders, and if you don't find any orders for that user, return null, but if you do find some, only return the first one (the earliest one based on timestamp).

If I use only a LEFT OUTER JOIN, it will return two rows for user 1, I don't want that. I thought of nesting the LEFT OUTER JOIN inside another select that would GROUP BY the other fields and fetch the MIN(TIMESTAMP) but that doesn't work either because I need to have "SPEC" in my group by, and since those two orders have different SPECs, they still both appear.

Any ideas on how to achieve the desired result is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way i can think of is using `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT *
FROM   Users u
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   Orders o
                    WHERE  u.ID = o.[USER]
                    ORDER  BY TIMESTAMP DESC) ou
```

Additionally creating a below `NON-Clustered` Index on `ORDERS` table will help you to increase the performance of the query

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ORDERS_USER
  ON ORDERS ([USER], TIMESTAMP)
  INCLUDE ([ITEM], [SPEC]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick :

```
SELECT  Users.ID, Orders2.USER ,  Orders2.ITEM ,  Orders2.SPEC ,  Orders2.TIMESTAMP
FROM    Users
LEFT JOIN 
        (
        SELECT  Orders.ID, Orders.USER ,  Orders.ITEM ,  Orders.SPEC ,  Orders.TIMESTAMP, ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM    Orders

        ) Orders2 ON Orders2.ID = Users.ID And RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a windowing function as a Cte:

```
with Sorted as
(
  select u.id as User, o.Item, o.Spec, o.Timestamp
         row_number() over (partition by u.Id order by Timestamp) as Row
    from Users u
    left join orders o
      on o.User = u.Id
)
select User, Item, Spec, Timestamp
  from Sorted where Row = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find lots of suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/25534279). The fact you have a left join is really incidental to what you're trying to do, so those answers should be easy to adapt to your problem. I agree with @MotoGP that for SQLServer an `OUTER APPLY` is probably the best approach. It is very similar to Postgres's `LATERAL JOIN` (mentioned in the other link).